# CICS Program Stack in COBOL

Tags: cobol, zos, cics

Is there a way of identify the program name in the call stack?
i.e., I've got a PGM X that links to a PGM B and this one links to a PGM C, and then, in C, I want to know which program originates the call (PGM X)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I also assume that the answer isn't always PGM A because sometimes PGM Z calls/links to PGM B. Which is it, a CALL or a LINK? What do you want to know, the program-id of the CALLer of PGM B, the name of the loadmember, what?

Comment: 1- It's a colleague of mine that has this "problem", because he wants to log the initial caller-id.
2- You assume right! If it was allways PGM A to be the caller, we didn't have the "problem"
3- It's a LINK.
4- In the case it's the same.

Comment: You're going to need to clarify your (their) question. If the answer is always PGM A, then there is no problem. Presumably it is not like that, but the question doesn't say. Is it using CALL or LINK? Or either? Or XCTL? If CALL, is it a static or dynamic CALL? Although there are ways to do this in retrospect, the best thing is to pass the desired log-information from the initial program.

Comment: I think I answered your doubts on my previous comment, but, nevertheless:
It's a LINK; the initial caller isn't allways the same, and yes, I told that too, but we still wonder if there isn't a "system" way!

Comment: Information should not be in comments, they are ephemeral. All the information should be in the questions/answers themselves. Your question is in the process of going "on hold" because such information is missing from it. There are a several ways to do it, as @cschneid  alludes. Although reliable, it is not simple, and will affect the performance orders of magnitude more than passing the data from the initial caller. If you can update your question with the requested information, plus a rationale for why an automatic way would be best, you'd get something, but it's not a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in CICS, you can do EXEC CICS ASSIGN and get the name of the current program with the PROGRAM option, and the program that linked to it with INVOKINGPROG. That will give you Program C and Program B in this case.

To get the original highest level program is more difficult. You can inquire on the current transaction (EIBTRNID) to get what program that runs, but if you've been routed somewhere then that won't be Program X but DFHMIRS for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it will take a little assembler.  Essentially, you need to chase up the save areas and execute a CSVQUERY on the return address, this will give you the name of the module that owns that save area.

There are a few quirks, you need to watch out for Cobol runtime modules (prefixed with IGZ) and/or Language Environment modules (prefixed with CEE).  When you do a Cobol Call, it invokes a runtime module that then calls the program you called.

Also, this will not identify programs that did a E. C. LINK or E. C. XCTL, only Cobol Call invocations that use OS save area conventions.

Example:

```
CSVQUERY SEARCH=JPALPA,INADDR=<R14_from_savearea>,OUTEPNM=<module_name_output>,MF=(E,PLIST)
```

Do that repeatedly for every return address on the save area chain and you will know all the callers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to do that.  Some people try chasing save areas and walking through the executable code to determine its name, but I suspect that all ends in tears.

One problem is that you have no guarantee of how LINK or XCTL have been implemented.  In the case of dynamic calls you might be able to follow the save area chain, but then you need to figure out how to identify the module.  Not something you're likely to be able to do in just COBOL.

Comment: Thanks @cschneid. I thought that, but it was worth to ask, we never know!